# Can a Brief Short-Circuit Event Damage a USB Phone Charger Permanently?

Tags: short-circuit

I'm hoping to gain some expert insight into a concern that's been troubling me. I've been using a USB phone charger which, according to the manual, has short-circuit protection. However, there was an incident where the charger's lightning connector briefly brushed against a metal key, which I'm afraid might have caused a short circuit, albeit a very brief one.

Although the charger seems to continue functioning normally after this event, I'm worried that some form of subtle, imperceptible damage might have occurred. That is, the charger might appear normal but has some underlying faults due to the suspected short-circuit incident.

My question is as follows:

Can a brief short circuit cause permanent damage to the charger, especially when it supposedly has short-circuit protection?
If it does get damaged, is it possible for this charger to cause harm to the devices it charges?
And if so, can this potential damage be passed onto other devices through means like data cables?
Lastly, assuming a device has been charged with this potentially faulty charger, can it return to normal operation after being charged with a properly functioning charger?

I understand the relationship between chargers and devices relies on voltage and current, so I'm looking for an understanding of whether an incident like this could have long-lasting effects on my charger and devices.

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: Everything is always possible. If it did short circuited, what could have happened depends on which exact pins were shorted, supply pins, data pins, supply to data, etc. Nobody knows what happened. If the charger still works and charges your phone, and your phone did not already blew up due to charger damage, it's likely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to answer without knowing the details of the product (e.g. circuit diagram, layout, placement of the components etc).

Short circuit protection is really a serious thing. Especially for off-the-line regulators there's a risk of shock or even fire, if the regulator is not designed properly. So, advertising a product as "short circuit protected" requires serious testing and verification. Some manufacturers put an extra statement like "don't short the outputs." even though the product is advertised as "short-circuit protected".

---

I remember I tested a supposedly-short-circuit-protected USB charger for public buses ([like this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_jacking)) by inserting my house key into the jack. It blew up instantly.

---

Generally, shorting the output right at the output connector pins may not cause a permanent damage because it's easier for the converter to survive since the natural feedback mechanism of the regulator stops the converter to operate, momentarily. But note that this is just because there's no voltage developed at the output. So this is the "voltage side" of the story. And there's also a "current side": Shorting the output may cause excessive currents to flow, regardless of the duration. If the converter doesn't have a proper overload protection (OLP) or the components are not properly selected/designed then the excessive currents may damage some of them (e.g. transformer wires, input filtering components, etc). Although they may not affect the normal operation of the converter in a short term, they may die eventually and so may the entire regulator.

Anyway... Again: it's difficult to give an exact answer. Anything or nothing could happen.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a follow-up question: I feel that the design of Apple's Lightning interface is very poor because all the pins seem to be exposed on the outside. Isn't this very likely to cause a short circuit? For instance, if it comes into contact with a metal handle or key while it is still powered?

Comment: @user11942 Before and during the design stage they do an FMEA (failure mode and effect analysis). The analysis covers almost all possible failures and their effects on either the customer/user or the product or even the company/brand. So if they ended up with a set of horrible results with lightning connector after the FMEA then they probably wouldn't release it. Of course the short circuit is one of those possible failures that should have been though about, so the charger and all the other equipment that use lightning connector should be designed w.r.t. the related effects and requirements.